# Passing values to main(int, char**)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I have a program that displays ascii values and letter, but now I have modify the program to display only the Spanish characters I am looking for. The program is called, yes, you got it, "ascii". What the user has to do is type `C:>ascii` or `C:>ascii all` to display all the ascii characters. To display only the Spanish characters the user must type `C:>ascii es`.

For this I have written this simple program

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argv[0] == "es"){
        abc::ascii_es();        
    }
    if(argv[0] == "all"){
        abc::ascii_all();
    }
    else
        abc::ascii_es();

    return 0;
}
```

but the program always jumps to the `ascii_es` method in the else condition keyword.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `argv[0]` is the path of the program itself. And you should probably use `strncmp` instead of `==`.

Comment: `strcmp` probably better than `strncmp`

Answer (score 5):

#### Issues:

1. You're not comparing strings, you're comparing pointers. You can fix this by changing one of the arguments to `std::string` or by using `strcmp(...) == 0`.
2. `argv[0]` is the name of your program. Use `argv[1]` for the first argument.
3. You're not checking that there are arguments to the program. And if there are none, then accessing `argv[1]` will cause undefined behavior.

#### Some working code:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2)
        abc::ascii_es();
    else if (argv[1] == std::string("es"))
        abc::ascii_es();        
    else if (argv[1] == std::string("all"))
        abc::ascii_all();
    else
        abc::ascii_es();
    return 0;
}
```